# How to store 2 integer in array list from result set and how to retrieve it

Tags: java, arrays

How to store 2 integer in array list from result set and how to retrieve it. 
I am trying to store the 2 integer to my array list and i don't know if get it correctly because when I am trying to retrieve it, it prints something like this 
'tryCheckout$checkout@4f4fffa4' Thanks guys. This is my code so far.

```
public class checkout{
    public int roomtypeid,itemid;
}

ArrayList<checkout> returncheckout = new ArrayList<checkout>();

try{                
*String query ="select ri.item_id, ri.roomtype_id from roomtype_tb as rt , roomtypeitem_tb as ri , room_tb as r , reserverooms_tb as rr where rt.roomtype_id = r.roomtype_id and rt.roomtype_id = ri.roomtype_id and ri.roomtype_id = r.roomtype_id and r.room_id = rr.room_id and rr.reservation_id = 10";
                PreparedStatement pst =conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();


                while(rs.next())
                {
                    checkout out = new checkout();
                    out.roomtypeid = rs.getInt("ri.roomtype_id");
                    out.itemid = rs.getInt("ri.item_id");

                    returncheckout.add(out);


                }

                returncheckout.forEach(System.out::println);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see your checkout class. Now I do. Change it to

```
public class checkout{
    public int roomtypeid,itemid;

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "roomtypeid =" + roomtypeid + ", itemid=" + itemid;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 0):

In your checkout class override the toString() method. That is a special method that gets called when an object gets passed to System.out.println. It will look something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "roomType=" + roomType + ", id=" + id;//Not sure what your variables are. You will need to change this line
}
```

I think your code is doing what you want, you just need the toString() method to print the result out like you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Java is actually returning the memory address for the object `checkout`. That is the weird numbers that are output to the screen. Add something like this to the `checkout` class.

```
public class checkout{
    public int roomtypeid, itemid;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Room Type ID: " + roomtypeid + " Item ID: " + itemid";
    }
}
```

The `toString()` method is called when the object is printed.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that :)